# Automatically initialized?

Tags: c++

The beginning of my class is:

```
class Player{
private:
    Cardpile hand;
    ...
}
```

Where Cardpile is another class. If I do `Player *p=new Player();` Is hand automatically initialized? I am asking this because I been trying to figure out a segmentation fault. I have looked everywhere in my code. The last thing I can think of is that `hand` is not initialized.

EDIT: This is the segmentation error I got. Card is a class inside of Cardpile. I know Card and Cardpile both works.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000402ac0 in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<Card*>::construct (this=0x6070a8, __p=0x4015c6, __val=@0x7fffffffe6d8) at /usr/include/c++/4.4/ext/new_allocator.h:105
105           { ::new((void *)__p) _Tp(__val); }
```

EDIT: Cardpile class:

```
class Cardpile : private vector<Card*> {
    public:
    using vector<Card*>::size;
    using vector<Card*>::at;
    Cardpile ();
...
}
Cardpile::Cardpile(){}
```

EDIT: Here is a cool fact: p==NULL does not check if p is initiated. I guess that's why I keep getting segmentation fault.

Comment: This depends on the constructor of your Cardpile class. Show the complete `Cardpile` definition, data members plus constructors, if any.

Comment: You would probably be much happier with a `std::vector<Card>` instead of a `std::vector<Card*>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't explicitly member initialize `hand` in your `Player` constructor, then the default constructor of `Cardpile` will be used.

If you haven't defined a default constructor, the compiler will create one.

When you compile and link your program with `-g`, gdb can show the stacktrace where your program crashed:

```
gdb program core
```

and then inside gdb enter `bt`. This will show the complete call stack at time of the segmentation fault.

Comment: The compiler-generated constructor for `Cardpile` can leave members of `Cardpile` un-initialized.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Yes, of course, this all depends on how `Cardpile` is defined. Until OP reveals `Cardpile` we can just guess.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what `Cardpile` is. If it's a POD, then no:

```
class Cardpile1{
   int x;
};
```

If it's not, then yes:

```
class Cardpile2{
   Cardpile2() : x(0) {}
   int x;
};
```

`hand` will exist for both cases, **but** reading from it is illegal if `Cardpile` is defined as a POD.

```
class Player{
  public:
    Cardpile1 hand1;
    Cardpile2 hand2;
};

Player p;
p.hand1.x;   //illegal
p.hand2.x;   //legal
```

Comment: I only have 1 instance of Cardpile in Player.

Comment: @user44322 I know, I put 2 to be clear. The first one is the POD class and is illegal to read from it. The second is not a POD, and reading from it is illegal. I named them Cardpile 1 and 2.

Comment: Since he value initializes `Player` it actually doesn't depend only on `Cardpile` whether it is a POD or not but on whether `Player` has a constructor or not! If `Player` does have a constructor, `Cardpile` gets whatever initialization is called from the constructor, otherwise it gets value initialized as well.

Comment: I did not initiate hand inside of Player();